# Original source of the persistence algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, algorithms, math-history, topological-data-analysis

Who was the first person/what was the first paper to invent/mention the persistence algorithm? (see page 6 of [these lecture notes](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~wang.1016/courses/5559/Lecs/Chap4-Persistence.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

That'd be Delfinado and Edelsbrunner in [An incremental algorithm for Betti numbers of simplicial complexes on the 3-sphere](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-8396(95)00016-Y). Check the last section. Similar algorithms may have been known by others, though, since persistent homology was discovered independently in a couple other places and worked on for a while before they all found one another.

Comment: remind me please, how do we find the persistence pairs from the betti numbers?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Indeed-- I dont have much more to add to it at the moment so all that remains is to announce. I think a few days after election is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence algorithm was first described in:
Barannikov, S. (1994). ["Framed Morse complex and its invariants"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267672645). Advances in Soviet Mathematics. 21: 93–115.